# this.watch not getting called in deferred.then()

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am having problem with something similar to following code with dojo deferred :-

This is XXX.js file

```
dojo.declare('XXX', [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated], {

postCreate: function() {
  //getting deferred from somewhere
  var _this = this;
  deferred.then(function(response) {
      console.log("This is getting printed");
      _this.watch("value", function(A, B, C) {
        console.log("This is not getting printed");
        var value = _this.get("value");
        _this.onValueChange(value);
  });

}
```

I call this class form other JS fle with following code :-

```
this.object = new XXX({ 
                    //some args
                }
dojo.connect(this.object, "onValueChange", function(value) {
                    console.log("I am here");
                    this.onValueChange(value);
});
```

When I was using same "watch" without deferred.then, it was working perfectly fine but now it is not executing the function when I change the value in form. Any pointers?
Could it be because when my "this.object" got created, the deferred didn't execute the function in "then" ?

Comment: The handler in `deferred.then` is probably not being called, would you mind adding the code of the actual deferred object accept/reject criteria?

Comment: I am able to print anything just above this.watch and inside deferred. Sorry, won't be able to put actual code due to privacy agreement with my company. But ya, this code is in postCreate() method and follows folowing lifecycle :- https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/_WidgetBase.html#id5

Comment: Then create a reduced case and preferably a fiddle. If you don't there is no way we'll be able to help you since the problem is not with the code your posted above, the code above in `.then` does not get called according to you which means the deferred gets rejected. No deferred accept code - no answer.

Comment: Just added more information in my question. Could you please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is onValueChanged ever called ?

Answer (score 0):

watch handlers are independent of the context they are added. They are just hooked onto the respective Stateful objects. In the above code, the end-braces of the watch block - `})` are missing. Maybe, that is the issue. Please refer a simple example below:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
    dojo.require("dojo._base.Deferred");
    dojo.require("dojo.ready");

    var def = null;

    dojo.ready(function(){
        def = new dojo._base.Deferred();
        var _this = dijit.byId('namefield');
        def.then(function(resp) {
          _this.watch("value",function(a,b,c) {
            console.info(''+a+'-'+b+'-'+c);
          });
        });
    });
    function func() {
        if(def) {
          def.resolve(true);
          console.info('resolved');
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <input type="text" dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="namefield" name="namefield"/>
    <button onclick='func()'>click</button>
</body>
```

And so, watch handler works even when added inside a deferred callback.
Moreover, i see that "onValueChange" is being called from within the event handler of "onValueChange", which is recursive and end up in stackoverflow error. also, "this" operator has a different context within "dojo.connect". Please take care about that too.